# Finding largest and min number in an array with functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a C program that calculates the min and max value from entered numbers. I managed find the min and max value, but for some reason i cannot print out the values outside the function. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find_largest_smallest(int a[], int n, int *largest, int *smallest)
{
    largest=smallest=a[0];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (largest<a[i])
            largest=a[i];
    }


    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        if (smallest>a[i])
            smallest=a[i];
    }
    printf("Largest is %d\n", largest);
    printf("smallest is %d\n", smallest);
}

int main()
{
    int elem;
    int i;
    int *x;
    int *y;

    printf("How many elements you want to store ?:");
    scanf("%d", &elem);
    int store[elem];
    for(i=0; i<elem; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a value to be stored:");
        scanf("%d", &store[i]);
    }

    find_largest_smallest(store, elem, &x, &y);

    printf("Largest value stored is %d and the smallest is %d.", *x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. And resolve them all. `largest=a[i];` - `largest` is a pointer to `int`, `a[i]` is an `int`.

Comment: `largest` -> `*largest` etc. And turn on those compiler warnings.

Comment: And you can set the `largest` and the `smallest` in the same loop (there is no need to iterate twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
largest=smallest=a[0];
```

Is wrong. You are assigning an integer to a pointer. What you should do is instead:

```
*largest = a[0];
*smallest = a[0];
```

Same goes for other assignments and reads:

```
if (*largest < a[i])
    *largest = a[i];

/* ... */

if (*smallest > a[i])
    *smallest = a[i];

/* ... */

printf("Largest is %d\n", *largest);
printf("smallest is %d\n", *smallest);
```

The declaration of `x` and `y` in main should just be `int` (not `int *`):

```
int x, y;
```

The call to `printf` in `main` is also wrong:

```
printf("Largest value stored is %d and the smallest is %d.", x, y);
//                         no asterisk needed here ----------^
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters largest and smallest have pointer types

```
void find_largest_smallest(int a[], int n, int *largest, int *smallest)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So within the function you have to dereference the pointers to access pointed objects.

For example

```
void find_largest_smallest(int a[], int n, int *largest, int *smallest)
{
    *largest = *smallest = a[0];
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i<n; i++ )
    {
        if ( *largest<a[i] )
            *largest=a[i];
    }


    for ( i = 1; i<n; i++ )
    {
        //printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        if ( *smallest>a[i] )
            *smallest=a[i];
    }
    printf("Largest is %d\n", *largest);
    printf("smallest is %d\n", *smallest);
}
```

Pay attention to that you could find the largest and the smallest elements using only one loop. Apart this the function should calculates pointers to the largest and smallest elements instead of their values because in general the user can pass the size of the array equal to 0. In this case the function will have undefined behavior.

Also within main the variables x and y should have the type int. That is

```
int x;
int y;

//...

printf("Largest value stored is %d and the smallest is %d.", x, y );
```

Comment: Does your answer really add anything new to Marco's?

Comment: @Adrian It seems we were writing answers simultaneously.

Comment: Happens a lot, I know!